# Can Thunderbird choose the correct account?

Tags: email, thunderbird

I have a question about sending a mail with mozilla thunderbird. I have several email-addresses and i want thunderbird to choose a certain account when i send an email to a certain recipient.

For example I have two accounts: `mail@myaddress.com` and `mail@anotheraddress.com`

If I send an email thunderbird uses per default `mail@myaddress.com`. So far so good. Sometimes I have to send an email to companies, where I have to use `mail@anotheraddress.com` as sender address. If I forget to switch the account theses companies get mails from the wrong mail address. Is there a way to connect a recipient emailaddress to an certain account?

Comment: Why are you asking this on SO? Are you planning to patch Thunderbird's source?

Comment: No, I just have several email-addresses and some of my clients should always receive my emails from a special email address. I wonder if there is a way to connect an email-account to a recipient, so that the recipient always gets my mail from this special account,

Comment: @user2969320, as a mitigation you could try this addon [Identity Chooser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/identity-chooser/): it forces you to choose the sender first, so you are less likely to send mails with the wrong one.

Comment: Hi Ruiz! That's a good addon! It's not exactly what i intended to find, but it will help me! Thx for this help!

Answer (score 0):

You can compose email using command line:

"preselectid" : an identifier for the "From" identity to choose from the menu*

```
note that you cannot directly specify an e-mail address but need to find the identity key
for example, "preselectid=id2" would select the identity #2
```

Reference:http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments_%28Thunderbird%29